# Elasticsearch connection refused [error 111]

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I am trying to connect **Django** (app) with **Elasticsearch** (8.x), using **Docker** to achieve that, install `django-elasticsearch-dsl` package and the required packages, then set in `settings.py` file:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'django-elasticsearch-dsl'
]

# Set Elasticsearch configuration.
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': ['http://localhost:9200'],
        'http_auth': (<username>, <password>),
    }
}
```

The Elasticsearch service has already configured to use `xpack.security.enabled: true` and create users/roles.

So, the services are running well BUT When trying to create and populate the Elasticsearch index and mapping by using following command in Django (app):

> docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py search_index --rebuild"

facing the following error:

> File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 197, in perform_request
> raise err from None
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection ob
> ject at 0x7f24bb9ff210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused))

Also the connection is refused when doing:

> docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "curl -X GET http://username:password@localhost:9200"

Showing:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Another thing to mention that is **Kibana** service is connecting normally with **Elasticsearch** using browser.

Any idea about the reason for this issue?

**The answer**:

The issue is related with **Elasticsearch** configuration in `settings.py` file, since I am using **Docker**, so I need to use the name of service instead of `localhost` as shown below:

```py
# Set Elasticsearch configuration.
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        # For Docker service:
        # http://<name_of_elasticesearch_service>:<port_of_service>
        'hosts': ['http://elasticsearch:9200'],
        'http_auth': (<username>, <password>),
    }
}
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker almost always means "the current container", not another container or the host system.  I've linked this to a question describing a multi-container PostgreSQL setup which you should be able to easily adapt here.  (`host.docker.internal` probably isn't the best way to connect to another container.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the response, the issue was in `hosts` value that should be:  `['http//:<name_of_elasticsearch_service_in_docker_compose:<port_of_service>']`